# Eclipse changed JRE for a project

Tags: eclipse, java-5, jrockit

I changed the `JRE` for a project in eclipse (Sun to JRockit). But when I try to run a class with main method I get a pop-up error message `"Could not find main class. Program will exit"` and `"Exception in thread "Main Thread" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Jrockit1/5"` in the console. I can see that the project got rebuilt (timestamp of class files). What else do I need to change? All of this is for `JRE 1.5`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you look at the Run configuration, does it use Sun or JRockit JVM. If you created your project before, it could have been set to the Sun JVM; which maybe cannot find some JRockit-specific classes.

Comment: I had checked that and it uses JRockit JVM.